# Is it possible to cancel a workflow activity in the MethodInvoking event handler?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I have a SharePoint workflow with a `SendEmail` activity. I use the `MethodInvoking` event handler to set the `To` property.

However, sometimes the workflow should not try to send an e-mail, because there is no e-mail address. I can detect such a condition in the `MethodInvoking` event handler. Is it possible to skip the `SendEmail` activity and proceed to the next one?

I know I can put `IfElseActivity` before `SendEmail`, but I am looking for a way to cancel activity execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the SDK, all activities have a Cancelling event. However, what I find seems to suggest that an activity is only cancelled if the entire workflow hits an error or is cancelled. It does not appear that you can manually cancel a single activity (I'm not sure the workflow would know what to do next). So an IfElse branch, or a ConditionedActivityGroup, would probably be your best shot.